# Where to save dynamic website text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to give the users of my ASP.NET website the possibility to write/change texts on the start site.
The texts are constantly changing and are therefore not static.

The texts are on the start page of the site, so saving it to the database wouldn't be the best choice, right? Because there would be a database access at every page call.

So my question is: What is the best practice to save this texts? Should I save it in the database? In a text file? xml file? In the web.config?

Edit: An example for the usage:
There is a "contact" area on the start page, the admin should be able to modifiy the content of this contact area. So this data not static, it should be editable.

Answer (score 4):

you can, of course, do many different things, but the normal thing is to just store it in a database and use a caching mechanism if you are concerned about round trips to database.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks the submit, button it has to go to the database. Edits and small changing will happen normally. Once the submition, is clicked, it has to go somewhere and a database call needs to happen. You can save it in session, but that will go away if the user goes away.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not a permanent data why not store it in Session?